# need get unique set of keys from Multiple dictionaries<Datetime,double>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, contains, hashset

I have 20 dictionaries of `<Datetime,double>` that are mostly for the same range of dates (e.g. feb 24-2012 through june 4 2012).  Some dictionaries have extra days, and some are missing days.  I want an array of all the unique dates being used.

Currently I'm iterating through all the keys and adding to a hashset to get a unique set, then converting the hashset to an array.  Is there a more efficient way?

For the record I also considered iterating through and using the containsKey function of the dictionary and add to a list, or LINQ.  My existing process seems to do the trick.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you described is the most efficient you can get.
You can do it with less code (and similar efficency) with LINQ:

```
dicts.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pull all the dictionaries into list that allow "duplicates in keys" and then use the Distinct function:

```
        Dictionary<DateTime, double> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>()
        {
            {DateTime.Now, 111}
        };

        Dictionary<DateTime, double> dic2 = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>()
        {
            {DateTime.Now, 111}
        };

        var list = dic.ToList();
        list.AddRange(dic2.ToList());

        var final = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while looking for a solution to a slightly different problem but used the accepted answer as the basis for my solution, so I thought someone with the same problem might come down this path too.

I was looking for a way to find a single property in a group of objects that was unique across the property set for each object.  I have the property names in dictionaries and I wanted a list of keys that only appear in one dictionary.

Here's my solution, which you should just be able to paste into linqpad to see it working.

```
void Main()
{
  var d = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
        {
            {
                "First",
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"A", "ash"},
                    {"B", "brett"},
                    {"R", "ripley"},
                    {"J", "jones"},
                    {"D", "dallas"}
                }
            },
            {
                "Second",
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"A", "ash"},
                    {"B", "brett"},
                    {"R", "ripley"},
                    {"D", "dallas"},
                    {"K", "kane"}
                }
            },
            {
                "Third",
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"A", "ash"},
                    {"B", "brett"},
                    {"R", "ripley"},
                    {"D", "dallas"},
                    {"V", "vasquez"}
                }
            },
            {
                "Fourth",
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"A", "ash"},
                    {"B", "brett"},
                    {"R", "ripley"},
                    {"D", "dallas"},
                    {"H", "hicks"}
                }
            }
        };

var u = d.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Keys).Distinct().Where(y => d.Values.SelectMany(z => z.Keys).Count(a => a == y) == 1).ToArray();

        foreach (var f in u)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", f, d.Keys.Single(s => ((Dictionary<string, string>)d[s]).ContainsKey(f)));
        }
```

}